# PHP, bitwise operations

Tags: php, bitwise-operators

I do not understand, code

```
var_dump(decbin(0xFFFFFFFF), 0xFFFFFFFF);
```

print

> string(32) "11111111111111111111111111111111" float(4294967295)

but if I get value using bitwise operations

```
$shift = 32;
$mask = ~((1 << (32 - $shift)) - 1);
var_dump(decbin($mask), $mask)
```

given

> string(32) "11111111111111111111111111111111" int(-1)

How I can get 4294967295 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP does not support unsigned integers, and its likely that you have a signed 32bit integer, which is -1 for all bits set.

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php

However, you may be able to print it out anyway using `printf('%u')`

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php